# discord bot edit role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a role that changes color permanently. I'm using discord.py rewrite.

A few hours ago it worked now I'm confused because it doesn't anymore. I changed nothing.

Here's my Code:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', description="description")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')


@bot.command()
async def rgb(ctx, time: int):
    colours = [0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF]
    i = 0
    selectedrole = ctx.guild.get_role(748128282859274251)

    while True:
        i = (i + 1) % 3
        print("This is printed")
        await selectedrole.edit(colour=discord.Colour(colours[i]))
        print("This will not be printed")
        await asyncio.sleep(time)


bot.run('xxxxx')
```

It doesn't run this line of code and just stops (program still running, nothing happens)

> await selectedrole.edit(colour=discord.Colour(colours[i]))

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: There're no errors

Comment: Never ever give your bot token in any code.

Comment: I changed to token to something random. It's not mine. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your bot is spamming the API so the edit code never gets awaited. You can try delete the role if a timeout error is detected and create the role again which may help a little but either way you should avoid spamming the API as it could get your bot account removed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to build in a timer and I wouldn't let this change by command. But mind that Discord don‘t like Rainbow roles or at least didn't like them back in 2018. I do not got any other information. [https://twitter.com/discord/status/1055182857709256704?s=20]

btw. you probably have to change your Bot-Token, because you leaked it here but anyway here is the code.

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', description="description")
TOKEN = 'YOUR NEW TOKEN'


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')


@bot.command()
async def rgb(ctx):
    colours = [0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF]
    i = 0
    selectedrole = ctx.guild.get_role(101010101010101)

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        i = (i + 1) % 3
        print("Color changed")
        await selectedrole.edit(colour=discord.Colour(colours[i]))


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I changed to token to something random. It's not mine. ;)